# How to generate a [1,1,1] according to a tensor of shape [5,4,3]?

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

I want to apply the operation tf.tile, e.g. tf.tile(A, [1, 1, b]) where A has shape [5,4,3]. How to generate [1, 1, 1] according to A? Then I set the [1, 1, 1]'s third element to b, where b is a placeholder.
This is my code, but it doesn't work, how to fix it?

```
d = tf.shape(A)
for i in range(tf.rank(A)):   #wrong, tf.rank(A) as a tensor can't be here
    d[i] = 1
d[2] = b
result = tf.tile(A, d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use  `tf.one_hot` to build your `multiples` tensor directly.

```
>>> b = 2
>>> tf.one_hot(indices=[b], depth=tf.rank(A), on_value=b, off_value=1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `tf.ones_like` to generate a tensor of 1 with the same shape as the Tensor passed as an argument.

```
>>> A = tf.random.uniform((5,4,3))
>>> tf.shape(A)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([5, 4, 3], dtype=int32)>
>>> tf.ones_like(tf.shape(A))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)>
```

Note that in tensorflow, you can't do item assignment on a tensor (so `d[2] = b` won't work for example). To generate your tensor `[1,1,b]` you can use `tf.concat`:

```
>>> b = 2
>>> tf.concat([tf.ones_like(tf.shape(A)[:-1]),[b]],axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually the location of b is arbitrary, so I have to cut the required tensor [1, 1, ..., b, ..., 1] into 3 pieces and concat them?

Comment: You can do that, or you can create a mask using `tf.one_hot` for example.

Comment: Using one_hot, the required tensor can be created as tf.one_hot(indices=[b_location], depth=tf.rank(A), on_value=b, off_value=1).

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Let me update my answer.

Comment: The parameter "indices" is set to the location of b, not b itself.